# resty gwt:Deferred binding failed for 'com.gwt.demo.client.PersonResourceAsync

Tags: resty-gwt

Hi i want to do project in gwt which is at client side and rest services at the server side,for this i am using **resty gwt** but i am getting an error:

> com.google.gwt.event.shared.UmbrellaException: Exception caught: Deferred binding failed for 'com.gwt.demo.client.PersonResourceAsync' (did you forget to inherit a required module?).

**Project description:-**

ide:- eclipse

I am using resty gwt jar  and i have included that jar from add external jar.I have also included in the gwt.xml as  `(<inherits name='org.fusesource.restygwt.RestyGWT'/>)`.I have also added that jar in war file lib folder. I have used one interface which extends restservice,in this interface while debugging i found that in the line i am getting nullpointerexception.

```
instance = GWT.create(PersonResourceAsync.class);
```

Please help me why i am getting this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure restyGWT jar is in your classpath ?

Can you post the code of your PersonResourceAsync ? Does it extends the RestService interface ?

Maybe you can have a look this [tutorial](http://ronanquillevere.github.io/2014/03/16/gwt-rest-app.html)